# Find sufficient and necessary conditions in which the function $g(t)$ has a finite limit when $t→0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let us consider the function: $$g(t)=\frac{α t^{x}+βt^{z}}{θt^{z}+λt^{y}}$$ where $α ,β,θ,λ,x,y,z$ are positive integers and $t∈[0,1]$.

My **question** is: Find sufficient and necessary conditions in which the function $g(t)$ has a finite limit when $t→0$

Comment: What type of a limit will you get if $\max{z,y}>\max{x,z}$ i.e. power of $t$ in denominator > that in numerator?

Comment: @GaurangTandon: I have already see this case. I want to see sufficient and necessary conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you meant no coefficient can be zero.

$u\mapsto t^u$ is a decreasing function on $u$ when $t\in[0,1]$ so:

- when $x<z$ then $\alpha t^x+\beta t^z\sim c\,t^x$ with $c=\alpha\neq 0$.
- when $x=z$ then $\alpha t^x+\beta t^z=c\,t^x$ with $c=\alpha+\beta\neq 0$. (since both $>0$, sum is $>0$)
- when $x>z$ then $\alpha t^x+\beta t^z\sim c\,t^z$ with $c=\beta\neq 0$.

Same kind of conclusion for the denominator.

So there exists some non-zero constant $c$ that depends on $\alpha,\beta,\theta,\lambda$ such that:

$g(t)\sim c\,\dfrac{t^{\min(x,z)}}{t^{\min(y,z)}}=c\,t^{\min(x,z)-\min(y,z)}$

which has a limit $\iff\min(x,z)-\min(y,z)\ge 0$

The condition is equivalent to $(x\ge y)$ or $(z\le x,z\le y)$.